# Sets of integers in the form $a^2 + 4ab + b^2$

Tags: contest-math

Let $A$ be the set of all integers of the form $ a^2 + 4ab + b^2$ where $a, b$ are integers

1. if $x, y$ are in $A$, prove that $xy$ is in $A$ (I have tried opening everything, it gets nowhere)
2. Show that $121$ is in $A$
3. Show that $11$ is not in $A$
4. Show that the equation $x^2 + 4xy + y^2 = 1$ has infinitely many integer solutions

Thank y'all for your help!

Comment: As an unhelpful comment (as usual I cannot find it) essentially the same question has been asked and answered on MSE, no more than $2$ weeks ago.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, there was a partial one which was self-deleted, perhaps by the same person, perhaps different  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702346/prove-121-is-in-the-set-z-without-guessing-and-checking

Comment: May I reassure you all that I searched quite a bit through the site, but I could not find an active answer which I can actually look at.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644861/if-both-integers-x-and-y-can-be-represented-as-a2-b2-4ab-prove-that  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692208/how-to-prove-that-certain-integers-and-xy-are-solutions-for-a-relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only the solution to part 4. I assume that you have seen solutions to the rest. If not, I strongly recommend reading [Ewan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644861/if-both-integers-x-and-y-can-be-represented-as-a2-b2-4ab-prove-that?lq=1).

**Solution 1:**

Apply Vieta's root jumping technique with a base case of $(4, -1)$. The result is immediate. This also explains why in Will's answer, you see that the $b$ and $a$ have the same (absolute) value. Note that you can multiply $a$ and $b$ by -1 and still get a solution.

**Solution 2:** In Ewan's answer, we get that

$$ f(ac−bd,ad+4bd+bc)=f(a,b)f(c,d). $$

which shows you how to 'multiply' solutions. Now, observe that $(4, -1)$ is a solution.

**Claim:** $ (4, -1)^n$ yields infinitely many distinct solutions.

Proof: You can easily show that $ ( 4, -1)^n \sim (4^n, ??)$

If you are familiar with Pell's Equation, Ewan draws the connection with the equation of the form $ x^2 - 3y^2 = 1$, which further explains / motivates why we likely can get all solutions through multiplication. It is not surprising that we reach a linear recurrence like that given in Will's answer, since the original Pell's equation also satisfies a linear recurrence.

Comment: Not sure anyone is going to ask about this with anything but that $4,$ but solutions to $a^2 - k \, ab+b^2 = 1$ are consecutive numbers in the sequence $-1,0,1,k,k^2-1,\ldots$ satisfying $x_{n+2}= k \, x_{n+1} -x_n.$ Here $k>2.$

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, and that follows directly from the Vieta jumping technique.

Comment: @Will These are special cases of well-known results on Pell equations, or equivalent results in quadratic fields (e.g. Richaud-Degert quadratics which have short continued fractions so small fundamental units). The associated descent in the group of integer points on a conic (realized by reflection) can be viewed as a special case of results on elliptic curves (if memory serves correct some of this folklore  is in Franz Lemmermeyer's "poor mans" papers).

Answer (score 6):

A clever trick (or a standard trick if you're familiar with using number fields to solve problems like these) to observe that

$$ a^2 + 4ab + b^2 = (a - b \alpha)(a - b \beta)$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the two roots of the equation $x^2 + 4x + 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Or, solutions given as $\frac{a}{b},$ beginning with a fake one with denominator zero, 
$$ \frac{1}{0},\frac{0}{1},\frac{-1}{4},\frac{-4}{15},\frac{-15}{56},\frac{-56}{209},\frac{-209}{780},\frac{-780}{2911}, $$

As you can see, both the sequence of numerators and the sequence of denominators satisfy $$  x_{n+2} = 4 x_{n+1} - x_n.   $$

The way I found this was a bit intricate, but a proof, by induction, that these keep working is easy. By switching to a negative sign for convenience, so $$ a^2 - 4 a b + b^2 = 1 $$ we get (all) solutions as consecutive values in the sequence
$$  -1,0,1,4,15,56,209,780,2911,\ldots  $$

The reason they probably feel this is suitable for a contest is that the $4$ does not really matter: The solutions to
$$ a^2 - 5 ab + b^2 = 1 $$ are consecutive numbers in
$$ -1,0,1,5,24,115,551,2640,12649, \ldots    $$
satisfying  $$  x_{n+2} = 5 \, x_{n+1} - x_n.   $$ 
For some positive $k > 2,$ the solutions to
$$  a^2 - k \, ab+b^2 = 1   $$
are consecutive numbers in $$ -1,0,1,k, \ldots  $$
satisfying  $$  x_{n+2} = k \, x_{n+1} - x_n.   $$

EddiTtT: It turns out this is not that pretty when considering the continued fraction for $\sqrt {k^2-4},$ partly because of the difference between odd and even $k.$ In the Lagrange cycle method that I prefer, it works very well: $\langle 1,k,1 \rangle$ is not reduced, but, with $k > 2,$ the equivalent form $\langle 1,k-2,2-k \rangle$  is reduced, and the entire Lagrange cycle is the shortest possible, length 2:
$$ 0: \langle 1,k-2,2-k \rangle; \; \; \; 1: \langle 2-k,k-2,1 \rangle; \; \; \;  2: \langle 1,k-2,2-k \rangle;   $$

Refresher course, why not. Given a discriminant $\Delta > 0$ but not a square, and integers such that $b^2 - 4 a c = \Delta,$ the form $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ refers to $$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2,  $$ and this is called reduced if two conditions hold, $$  ac < 0 \; \mbox{and} \; \; b > |a+c|.  $$ Probably not obvious, but these imply $|a|, b, |c| < \sqrt \Delta.$

Answer (score 0):

1.) We can see that, $a^2 + b^2 + 4ab = (a+2b)^2 - 3b^2 = u^2 - 3v^2$. Also, $u$ and $v$ can take all integer values. Now, $u^2 - 3y^2 = (u + \sqrt 3)(u - \sqrt 3)$. So, $A = \{\,N(\alpha)\,\mid\,\alpha\in\mathbb Z(\sqrt 3)$. We know that $N(\alpha\beta) = N(\alpha)N(\beta)$, so if $x = N(\alpha) \in A$ and $y = N(\beta) \in A$, then $z = N(\alpha) \in A$.

4.) Now if $N(\alpha) = 1$, then $N(\alpha^k) = 1\,\forall k \in \mathbb N$. Consider $\alpha = 2 + \sqrt 3$, $|\alpha| > 1$, hence if $m < n \implies |\alpha^m| < |\alpha^n|, \implies \alpha^m \neq \alpha^n$. So $B = \{\,\alpha^n\,\mid\,n\in\mathbb N\}$, is an infinite solution set of $N(\alpha) = 1$.